# Verben mit Präpositionen und Infinitive

Tags: difference, verb-usage, infinitive

Wenn man ein Verb mit einer Präposition plus einem Infinitiv hat, verwendet man manchmal "darum", "danach", "dafür"... manchmal sagt man die Präposition einfach nicht.

Zum Beispiel:

> Die Delphine träumen davon, mit mir zu schwimmen.
>
> Ich sorge mich darum, dass er eine Arbeit findet.

und

> Die Delphine träumen, mit mir zu schwimmen.
>
> Ich sorge mich, dass er eine Arbeit findet.

Was ist der Unterschied dazwischen? Sind sie beide richtig?

Comment: *Darum*, *danach*, *dafür* sind Adverben, keine Präpositionen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sehen wir uns zuerst die marginalen Bedeutungsunterschiede in diesen Beispielen an:

> Die Delphine träumen davon, mit mir zu schwimmen.

klingt, als würden sich die Delfine wünschen, mit dir zu schwimmen, während

> Die Delphine träumen, mit mir zu schwimmen.

schlicht und ergreifend heißt, dass sie im Schlaf davon träumen, mit dir zu schwimmen. Es ist allerdings nichts so, als könnte ich nicht sagen "Sie träumen von dir." im Sinne von im Schlaf träumen. Nur mit einem Objektsatz (dass) oder einer Infinitivgruppe deutet die Präposition "davon" tendenziell auf einen Wunsch hin.

> Ich sorge mich, dass er eine Arbeit findet.

würde so verstanden werden, dass ich mir Sorgen mache, ob er eine Arbeit findet.

> Ich sorge mich darum, dass er eine Arbeit findet.

würde allerdings so verstanden werden, als würde ich mich darum bemühen, dass er eine Arbeit findet (indem ich ihm Stellenausschreibungen suche etc.)

Es gibt dazu aber keine Regeln. Das hängt einfach vom entsprechenden Verb ab. Dazu auch bei [canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/index.html):

> Wenn der Nebensatz die Funktion eines Präpositionalobjekts hat, kann
>   er durch ein Pronominaladverb der Form da(r)- im Hauptsatz vertreten
>   sein:
>
> > Sie ärgert sich (darüber), dass sie den Zug verpasst hat. Er zweifelt
> >     (daran), dass sie die Wahrheit sagt. Ich bin (damit) einverstanden,
> >     früher wegzufahren.
>
> Oft ist das Korrelat obligatorisch:
>
> > Sie reden darüber, wie sie das Problem lösen sollen. Er beharrt
> >     darauf, seine Tochter jede Woche sehen zu dürfen. Ich habe mich damit
> >     abgefunden, dass ich es nie schaffen werde.
>
> Ob das Korrelat obligatorisch oder fakultativ ist, hängt vom Verb des
>   Hauptsatzes ab.